# Rails 3.1 nested forms validation translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-forms

I'm try to translate validation error message using YAML aliases

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Пользователь
      profile: Профиль
    attributes:
      profile: &profile_attributes
        name: "Отображаемое имя"
        ya_login: 'Логин на Яндексе'
        description: 'Описание'
      user:
        password: Пароль
        profile_fields:
          <<: *profile_attributes
```

or without YAML aliases, like this:

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: Пользователь
      profile: Профиль
    attributes:
      profile: &profile_attributes
        name: "Отображаемое имя"
        ya_login: 'Логин на Яндексе'
        description: 'Описание'
      user:
        password: Пароль
        profile_fields:
          name: "Отображаемое имя"
          ya_login: 'Логин на Яндексе'
          description: 'Описание
```

But I receive:

> Profile ya login не может быть пустым

Where can be mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5665-label-form-helper-and-i18n-with-nested-attributes-does-not-work that helped me find out how to translate nested forms.

Form example:

```
form_for(@post) do
  fields_for(:author) do
    label :name
  end
end
```

This does not work for me:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      author:
        name: Nom
```

But this works:

```
fr:
  helpers:
    label:
      post[author_attributes]:
        name: Nom
```

And if you want to stay DRY:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post:
        [...]
      author: &author_attributes
        name: Nom

  helpers:
    label:
      record[author_attributes]:
        <<: *author_attributes
```

I've found several issues/comments related to nested forms i18n:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3441

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c19bd4f88ea5cf56b2bc8ac0b97f59c5c89dbff7

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1869

They should improve documentation about how to translate nested forms.

Comment: Seems this has changed after 3.2, found an answer here http://www.soulcutter.com/blog/2013/localization-of-nested-attributes-in-rails-3-dot-2/